Why is Node.js 20.x runtime in AWS Lambda not working with ffprobe?
I am trying to upgrade my lambda function from Node.js 16.x to 20.x. I am using ffprobe 6.1 in a lambda layer. The function returns the starting time code of a .ts video file. The function runs perfectly with Node.js 16.x and 18.x. I can also run the function on my laptop using node 20.12.2, and it works as expected.
Here is the code
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { spawnSync } from 'child_process';

const ffprobeExecutable = '/opt/bin/ffprobe';

const early = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06'];

function doCmd(cmd) {
  const args = cmd.split(/\s+/);
  try {
    const output = spawnSync(args[0], args.slice(1), { encoding: 'utf8' });
    console.log('output.stdout', output);
    return output.stdout;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`An exception occurred:\n${e}`);
    throw e;
  }
}

async function getStartingTimecode(event) {
  console.log(event);
  const url = event.url;
  if (url.includes('.m3u8')) {
    const timezone = url.match(/start=.*-0(.*?):.*&/)[1];
    console.log(timezone);
    if (timezone === '7') {
      early.push('07');
      console.log(early);
    }

    const masterManifestResponse = await fetch(url);
    const masterManifestText = await masterManifestResponse.text();
    const masterManifestList = masterManifestText.split('\n');
    const hostname = url.split('/dvr')[0];

    for (let index = 0; index < masterManifestList.length; index++) {
      if (masterManifestList[index].includes('1920x1080') && !masterManifestList[index].includes('I-FRAME')) {
        console.log(`child_manifest: ${hostname}/${masterManifestList[index + 1]}`);
        const childManifestResponse = await fetch(`${hostname}/${masterManifestList[index + 1]}`);
        const childManifestText = await childManifestResponse.text();
        const childManifestList = childManifestText.split('\n');

        // Get the first file of the manifest
        const videofile = `${hostname}/${childManifestList[7]}`;
        console.log(`videofile: ${videofile}`);

        // Build ffprobe command
        const cmd = `${ffprobeExecutable} -i ${videofile} -read_intervals %+#1 -v quiet -hide_banner -select_streams v:0 -show_frames -of json`;
        const startTC = JSON.parse(doCmd(cmd));
        console.log('ffprobe response:', startTC);
        const timecodeRaw = startTC.frames[0].side_data_list[0].timecodes[0].value.split(':');
        console.log('start timecode', startTC.frames[0].side_data_list[0].timecodes[0].value);
        console.log('start timecode hours', timecodeRaw[0]);

        // Convert the timecode to Salt Lake City time
        let hours;
        if (early.includes(timecodeRaw[0])) {
          hours = 24 + parseInt(timecodeRaw[0].slice(-1)) - parseInt(timezone);
        } else {
          hours = parseInt(timecodeRaw[0]) - parseInt(timezone);
        }
        const min = timecodeRaw[1];
        const sec = timecodeRaw[2];
        const frames = timecodeRaw[3];

        console.log('Returned Time', `${hours}:${min}:${sec}:${frames}`);
        return { startTime: `${hours}:${min}:${sec}:${frames}` };
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Used by MediaPackage_Harvest_Transcode_Job_Create_Step2 to determine the starting timecode of the first segment of the clip
    const cmd = `${ffprobeExecutable} -i ${url} -read_intervals %+#1 -v error -hide_banner -select_streams v:0 -show_frames -of json`;
    const startTC = JSON.parse(doCmd(cmd));
    console.log(startTC);
    return { startTime: startTC.frames[0].side_data_list[0].timecodes[0].value };
  }
}

export const handler = (event) => {
  getStartingTimecode(event);
};

Here is the output of the doCmd function:
output.stdout {
status: null,
signal: 'SIGSEGV',
output: [ null, '', '' ],
pid: 20,
stdout: '',
stderr: ''
}
I have tried using different builds of ffprobe, like markus-perl and ffbinaries.
I have tried different npm packages like ffprobe-installer
I have tried using an ffmpeg layer instead and calling ffprobe from that.
I'm really hoping it is something simple that I have overlooked.
Has anyone else experienced this and know how to fix it?

Did you find any solution to this problem @Dustin Hales?

I am also facing the same problem. I see that ffprobe fails during DNS resolution. I could reproduce the problem by pulling the runtime image. Locally, it worked after installing and running nscd command, however, this is not a solution for the Lambda runtime.
